# Where do I  set the $id variable in this PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm troubleshooting this code, I am very new to PHP, so any help would be appreciated.

I think the error is coming from not having the `$id` variable set anywhere, so where do I set it?

Here is the code:

```
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE depot = 'plainview'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Count table rows
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

//error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$result1 = false;

//update
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

$sql1 = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET 

available='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['available'][$i])."', 
rent='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rent'][$i])."',  
corp_ready='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['corp_ready'][$i])."', 
down='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['down'][$i])."',  
gfs='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gfs'][$i])."', 
dateTime = NOW()   
WHERE id='".$id[$i]."'";



$result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
}
}

//redirect
if($result1){
header("location: success.php");
}
else
header("location: fail.php");


?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script language="JavaScript1.1" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function mm_jumpmenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
  eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
  if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}
//-->
</script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <p>Plainview, North East Region</p>
    <p>Select a different region: <select onchange="mm_jumpmenu('parent',this,0)" name="lostlist">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Choose Your Depot</option>
                <option value="plainview.php">Plainview</option>
                <option value="worcrester.php">Worcrester</option>

                </select></p>
</div><Br />

<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Product Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Available</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Rent</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Corp Ready</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Down</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>GFS</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td align="left"><?php $id[]=$rows['id']; ?><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>

<td align="left"><?php echo $rows['product']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><input name="available[]" type="text" id="available" value="<?php echo $rows['available']; ?>" size="5"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="rent[]" type="text" id="rent" value="<?php echo $rows['rent']; ?>" size="5"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="corp_ready[]" type="text" id="corp_ready" value="<?php echo $rows['corp_ready']; ?>" size="5"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="down[]" type="text" id="down" value="<?php echo $rows['down']; ?>" size="5" /></td>
<td align="center"><input name="gfs[]" type="text" id="gfs" value="<?php echo $rows['gfs']; ?>" size="5"></td>

</tr>
<?php
}
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
<?php

mysql_close();

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Per the statement:

```
if($result1){
header("location: success.php");
}
else
header("location: fail.php");
```

Every time I try to access the page it redirects to `fail.php`, so why does it fail?

Comment: your form is never submitted, $result1 is always false.

Comment: When asking a question, reduce your code and anything else needed, to the least number of lines as possible. Strip out everything that is not needed, otherwise people will refuse to help because you're making them do too much work figuring out what you want.

Comment: You should just look at what `echo('<pre>'); print_r ($id);` gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `$_POST['Submit']` is not set, or `$count` is 0.

Comment: i think $count is 0 because $id is not set anywhere, how and where do i set it?

Comment: No, `$count` would be 0 because the query that sets it returns 0 rows.

Comment: I don't know that it does. Read my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($result1 === true){
header("location: success.php");
} else {
header("location: fail.php");
}
```

Comment: Actually the curly braces are not required if there's only one line of code that would go inside of them. :)

Comment: i did that and now i get Notice: Undefined variable: id plainview.php on line 36

Comment: Peter, that depends entirely on what you're trying to do. Where does the id come from in the first place? Is it in $_POST like the other values you have?

Comment: Oh, I see your problem. You need to do `mysql_fetch_array()` on whatever you're using for `$id`. Otherwise, it returns null.

Comment: Basically, do this: 
`$id = mysql_fetch_array($result);`

Comment: @Compeek, id is not in $_POST, it is the primary key in the database.  The id determines which row is actually updated

Comment: As long as it's after your query and before you use it, anywhere. I'd put it after where you define `mysql_num_rows()`.

Comment: ok i added it after mysql_num_rows() is defined and now i get this error: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2011-04-27 15:11:56'

Comment: $id is not an array containing all the primary keys if you just use `$id = mysql_fetch_array($result)`

Comment: See my answer for looping through results and make $id the correct usable array.

Comment: @capsule, i have included the header() statement inside the if statement as your answer said to do and now i get Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2011-04-27 15:11:56'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed a line, But I don't see where you put a value to $id... The first time you mention it is where you expect to receive a value from it.

Comment: First, print count, so we will have some sort of debugging... second, why do you need the ID in the where clause... - what does it represents? If you want to go over all id's, you don't need this where clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't post anything, `$result1` will remain false.
If you post something, the test will only be done on the last iteration of your loop, so every other UPDATE could fail but the last one, it would be considered as a success.

Btw, why do you have some code after your redirection? It will obviously never be displayed.
You also need to `exit()` after any `header('Location')` to avoid unwanted code execution (code that would remain after the header call).

I think you might want to include the `header()`instructions INSIDE the `if(isset($_POST['Submit']))` test to avoid being redirected just by loading the page without posting anything.

`Location` should also be a complete URL with protocol and domain, even if most browser will accept a partial own, this is violating some RFCs.

You also need to loop through results to defined `$id`:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $id[] = $row['primary_column_name'];
```

Comment: thank you, i have updated the header() statement to be included in the if statement!

Comment: after `$result=mysql_query($sql);` (I corrected a typo in my answer, $result and not $results)

Comment: thanks, I updated my page with that.  now the page does not return any results....any recommendations?

Comment: It's because you loop twice through the results (once in the code before the page and once in the "template"). You have to reset the results by using `mysql_data_seek($result, 0)` before the second loop.